# I can ping but cannot download from the internet

Tags: linux, ping, wget

When using the system proxy, firefox has no access to internet. After changing the proxy to auto, firefox downloads fine.

In the terminal, when I tried to download using wget, the ternimal stopped at

```
>>wget www.google.com
--2015-06-05 23:38:09--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 216.58.211.100, 2a00:1450:4007:80d::2004
Connecting to www.google.com|216.58.211.100|:80...
```

other programs also don't have access

```
>>pip install obspy
Collecting obspy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2ff764ced0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/obspy/
```

but I can ping

```
>>ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.211.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par03s15-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from par03s15-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from par03s15-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from par03s15-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.100): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from par03s15-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.100): icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=14.1 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4498ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.120/14.163/14.202/0.032 ms

>>ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=7.96 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=54 time=8.06 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=54 time=7.96 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=54 time=8.01 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=5 ttl=54 time=7.98 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.964/7.998/8.060/0.067 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your proxy. Your environment would be useful here (linux? Windows?) but I'm guessing linux.

You need to find your actual proxy settings (which firefox is picking up) - a little guesswork would be needed here but [you can use curl](https://serverfault.com/questions/111463/when-using-autoproxy-how-can-you-see-the-proxy-configuration) and test each known [automatic proxy url or possible variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol).

Then you need to set a http_proxy environment variable which would work on both pip and wget.

Comment: Works after I export http_porxy. Thx.